# Rails: Is it possible to assign PostgreSQL database entries to Vue in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, vue.js

I'm trying to do a CRUD for a PostgreSQL database in Rails using Vue.JS. I've looked around and I can't find any documentation on how to do it. Essentially, what I want to do is take--

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Foo' },
      { message: 'Bar' }
    ]
  }
})
```

-- and instead of defining the messages manually, as is done in that example from the Vue.JS website, I want to have the items defined with "Table.Column" as it relates to my PostgreSQL database.

I have the PostgreSQL data displaying when I just use the Rails controller with applicable tags within the html.erb file, but that's not the way I need for it to be done. I need something like `message: @table.each` / `message: @table.columnName` , but that's not working, so whatever the correct way to do it is instead.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It's of course *possible*. The rough logic is that you're de-coupling the front-end from the back-end, and as such you can access back-end (Rails) from the front-end (Vue) with routes.

```
mounted: function() {
  this.$http.get(`/api/v1/items`) // or whatever
    .then(response => {
      this.items = response.body.items
  })
}
```

As long as your controller renders your `items` correctly it'll work. Obviously things like authentication can be applied to this kinda logic.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need Hstore to do this?